# Why SELECT shows Update lock in deadlock graph

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-deadlocks

I have two SQL queries (MSSQL server):

```
SELECT [Value]
FROM [dbo].[BigTable]
ORDER BY [Id] DESC
```

and

```
UPDATE [dbo].[BigTable]
SET [Value] = [Value]
```

Where [Id] - Primary clustered key.
When I run them infinitely in the loop I get deadlock, which is obvious. But what is not obvious (for me): why on deadlock graph I get "Owner mode: U" for select statement.
[image]
As far as I know select statement can only have shared locks. And here I'm not using any hints or additional transactions to make update lock. Any idea why I see it here?

XML for deadlock is attached

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process1c094ee5468">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process1c094ee5468" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 7:1:1502 " waittime="1289" ownerId="901143" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2021-05-05T18:04:54.470" XDES="0x1c094329be8" lockMode="S" schedulerid="6" kpid="22644" status="suspended" spid="62" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-05-05T18:04:54.470" lastbatchcompleted="2021-05-05T18:04:54.453" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.453" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="ALEXEY-KLIPILIN" hostpid="3132" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="901143" currentdb="7" currentdbname="SampleDb" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="92" sqlhandle="0x02000000bf49f5138395d042205ae64888add734815151770000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[BigTable] ORDER BY Id DESC    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process1c096e1d088" taskpriority="0" logused="100" waitresource="PAGE: 7:1:1503 " waittime="1289" ownerId="901139" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2021-05-05T18:04:54.470" XDES="0x1c08bc84428" lockMode="X" schedulerid="4" kpid="9160" status="suspended" spid="61" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-05-05T18:04:54.470" lastbatchcompleted="2021-05-05T18:04:54.397" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.397" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="ALEXEY-KLIPILIN" hostpid="3132" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="901139" currentdb="7" currentdbname="SampleDb" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="88" sqlhandle="0x0200000018eeb102d311fd032bb670822f260841060b64410000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
UPDATE [dbo].[BigTable] SET [Value] = [Value]    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1502" dbid="7" subresource="FULL" objectname="SampleDb.dbo.BigTable" id="lock1c0884bdd00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594043760640">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process1c096e1d088" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process1c094ee5468" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1503" dbid="7" subresource="FULL" objectname="SampleDb.dbo.BigTable" id="lock1c0a0a23380" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594043760640">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process1c094ee5468" mode="S"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process1c096e1d088" mode="X" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Comment: Please confirm: `SELECT` query is not in a transaction with other queries? There are definitely no hints on `BigTable`? `BigTable` is a table not a view?

Comment: Can you paste the XML for the deadlock graph?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, no hints, no transactions

Comment: The XML attached just has `S` no `U` - edit no I do see `mode="U"`

Comment: But I think the `U` lock is actually held by the `UPDATE` tran. The `SELECT` just holds an `S` lock. The Graphical UI is showing the wrong info. process1c094ee5468 holds an S lock, process1c096e1d088 holds a U lock and is trying to convert it to an X lock

Comment: But in that case I would see two `S` I thought and two `U` or `X`. That `mode="U"` in XML is a bit confusing

Comment: Ok, so, some issue with graphical representation, right. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just looks like some misrepresentation in the graphical representation.

process1c096e1d088 (the `UPDATE`) holds a page level `X` lock on page 1502 and a page level `U` lock on 1503 and is trying to convert that `U` lock to an `X`  lock. (`requestType="convert"`)

process1c094ee5468 (the `SELECT`) holds a page level `S` lock on 1503 (compatible with the `U` lock) and is waiting for a page level `S` lock on 1502.

Because the page lock `1503` is held in both `S` and `U` modes it has `mode="U"` in the deadlock XML and the UI assumes it is held by the blocker in that mode.

Of course if the `SELECT` transaction was to release its lock on 1503 before requesting the lock on 1502 this deadlock could not arise but I assume there is a good reason for it not doing this (maybe to stop 1502 getting deallocated mid scan and leaving it with no next page to visit).